# Not notified of my answer getting edited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, notifications

I used to get notified when my answer got edited. I didn't get notified of this [today](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27205601/3)<sup>[1]</sup>.

I've noticed this before on answers that had received a comment at the same time, so I thought the comment notification also served as the edit notification, but this time, I didn't get any notification at all.

Was this change intentional? I consider this a bug. Over the years, I've had numerous edits which introduced errors into my answer<sup>[2]</sup>. I'm a [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) expert, and I would like to review any edits made to my answers.

I also commonly fix details in other answers, and I'm dismayed to learn that the people whose answers I have edited haven't been receiving notifications of this. I was relying on it.

---

1. Ironically, this very post received an [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/278089/2) that didn't trigger a notification.
2. That's not the case in the edit I mentioned above; it was perfectly valid typo fix.

Comment: (This is probably not the first time it's been asked, but I couldn't find a duplicate.)

Comment: Which edit were you expecting a notification for? I do know ["trivial edits"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415) and I think tag-only edits do not trigger notifications.

Comment: The word "today" links to such an edit. It was a trivial edit. I'm not sure how SO judges what is trivial or not, though. Changing `and` to `or` can make a significant change.

Comment: Perhaps that would be worth a new question if you actually get a non-trivial edit that SO has judged as trivial. I understand where you're coming from, and am a bit shocked myself, but without concrete examples of problems caused by the system behaving as intended, experience has shown me there's no point in arguing that the system design has flaws.

Comment: @hwd, How about [this](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/20935/revisions)? I just negated a statement in someone's answer, and I doubt they got notified. Do you really think people's answers are getting edited so often that some of the notifications needs to be blocked?

Comment: Please change status to "status-brokenbydesign". This is bad.

Comment: @ikegami Like I said, I'm a bit shocked myself. I'm agreeing with you. The thing is, though, that if there is no concrete example of a problem, others (not me) will claim that they see no evidence of a problem, and therefore there is no problem, and nothing will change. As indicated by the status-bydesign tag this question has received.

Comment: @hvd, Your logic is completely backwards. You shouldn't be asking if suppressing the notifications causes problems because it obviously does. (Below, 52 people indicated it's a problem for them.) You should be asking yourself: 1) What problem does suppressing the notifications solve, and 2) how does the severity of that problem compare to the severity of suppressing notifications. No matter how I do the math, I just can't imagine the number of notifications being suppressed it large enough to annoy anyone if they weren't suppressed.

Comment: @ikegami *Again*, I'm agreeing with you that there is a problem. However, neither your opinion nor mine matters. I'm trying to explain why nothing here will change the opinion of more important people: it seems clear to me that they do not currently see suppressed notifications as a problem, and it seems likely to me that nothing that's currently posted here is going to change their minds.

Comment: @hvd, The fact that we perceive a problem is a problem. The problem is that this features makes us feel some mix of uncomfortable / violated / distrustful / paranoid / rude / deceived / deceiving / ???.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This appears to be [broken by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415) -- the design suppresses notifications whenever the software decides a change was "too minor to bother the user with".

As stack overflow is not currently running an AI capable of understanding the import of swapping `Trust` for `Truth` in an answer, it appears that it considers small text edits to be mostly too minor (there may be other, unknown heuristics).

As a workaround if this is not fixed (or until it is fixed), `stackoverflow.com/users/USER_ID/?tab=responses&sort=revisions` with `USER_ID` being your user ID will give you a dump of all revisions done to your content on a particular website.

Comment: +1 for the revisions link - I had no idea how many of my posts had been revised until I saw this. Thankfully most of them were good edits that improved my contributions, but I was surprised.

Comment: I'm toying with the idea of making a minor vandalizing edit to this node... :)

Answer (score 13):

Notifications are being sent out, but they are intentionally [suppressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415) for trivial edits.

Comment: You can check your response tab > revisions from time to time for any revision made on your post by other people.

Comment: 100% agree with @canon: anyone editing my answer (or question) is an event I want to know about.  I don't care if it is trivial; I want to know.  I may not do more than look at what was done, but I want to know that it was altered so I can validate what they did to my work.

Comment: One of my pet hates is over-use of in-line code back-ticks.Someone edited one of my answers to put "underflow" and "infinity" in back-ticks, even though I was using them as English words, not code quotes. The change only involved a few characters, but did not seem trivial to me.

Comment: @canon, I remember seeing an interface that could mine SO's data. Could it be used to find out the number of trivial edits to which the average user has been subjected? If the the purpose of restricting the notifications is to reduce notication spam, let's put some numbers on the volume.

Comment: It's not clear what qualifies as trivial. Is adding four characters "trivial"? What if the four characters are `N` `O` `T` and a space"?

Comment: @EuroMicelli [According to Kevin Montrose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have#comment378020_135411), "a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy). For the 'technical' sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to code of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial." This was in June, 2012, so it could well have changed, but that's the most concrete statement I could find from the powers that be.

Comment: So changing "true" to "false" or inserting "not " is a trivial change. So is scattering random back-ticks, as long as one inserts no more than five pairs. I think the whole "trivial edit" system needs  a design and usability review.