# Why wasn't I notified of a new answer to my question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783275/adding-an-xcode-subproject-shouldnt-all-the-source-files-get-copied) yesterday. I looked at it again today and was surprised to find that it had an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36785916/3681880) even though I hadn't gotten a red update notice.

[image]

Looking at my notifications, there was nothing there. (I did get that other notification 21 hours ago.)

[image]

I assume this is a bug?

## Update

This question is not a duplicate of [Not notified of my answer getting edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/not-notified-of-my-answer-getting-edited). In that question the notification was purposefully suppressed because the answer **edit** was too minor to warrant a notification. In my situation, I didn't get a notification for a **new answer** to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not notified of my answer getting edited](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/not-notified-of-my-answer-getting-edited)

Comment: @Laurel, I don't think so. In that question the notification was suppressed because it was a minor edit. Here I didn't get a notification for an entire answer.

Comment: Maybe the deletion during the grace period messed up the notification?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, I'm pretty sure I had already awarded that grace period bounty before the time in question here, but I suppose that it could be related.

Comment: @Suragch: I meant the answer's initial-revision grace period.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, Oh, I see. Currently I can't check the exact times of the question and answer posts because they just say "yesterday".

Comment: @Suragch Generally you can hover over *yesterday* to get the exact time. However, in this case, for a better overview, check out the timeline of the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36783275/timeline) and the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36785916/timeline). Click on *toggle format* to see the exact times.

Comment: @Matt, Good to know. I didn't know about the hovering or the timeline.  So the question was asked at 2016-04-22 01:37:18Z and answered at 2016-04-22 05:53:01Z. The answer, delete, undelete, and editing history is a little strange. I'm guessing this is related to why the notification didn't go through.

Comment: My guess is that you got a notification, but the answer was subsequently deleted which nullifies that notification. Then perhaps an undelete doesn't create a further notification.

Comment: ...so  if there is no existing notification with a "read" flag shouldn't the un-deletion of answer create a notification (or if the previous notification was soft deleted, mark it as un-deleted as well)..?

Comment: @Suragch I'm thinking my comment might be better as an answer, fancy testing out the notifications on it and see if it's correct? I can add the answer, delete it and undelete. You can check your notifications all the way through...

Comment: @DavidG, good idea. I'll let you know what I get.

Comment: @DavidG, It looks like it is as you said. I'll edit your answer with an image. You can then update your answer again after that however you would like.

Comment: @Oded now notifications follow the status of the post (ie. post deleted, notification removed; undeleted, notification re-added) or something else?

Comment: @Braiam - not that I am aware. A deleted post would usually also delete the notification, but that's it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The timeline went like this:

1. The answer was submitted and you should have gotten a notification, though you may have missed it because;
2. The answer was then deleted which in turn deleted the notification.
3. Finally the answer was un-deleted but this doesn't cause a new notification to get created.

As I have deleted and undeleted this answer, we should see the same sequence of events (hope this edit doesn't confuse things further!)

## The view from Suragch's notification inbox:

Just before DavidG posted this answer, Suragch's notification inbox looked like this:

[image]

As DavidG added his answer and another comment, for a brief moment there were two notifications.

[image]

Just as Suragch was clicking the notification, the 2 became a 1.

[image]

And there was no notification to be seen at all of this answer.

Comment: So I would classify this as a bug, though somewhat minor since most people don't delete and undelete their their answers. I don't know what the technical challenges of fixing this bug would be, but it would still be nice to get it fixed.

Comment: Not sure it's a bug or [meta-tag:status-by-design], perhaps worthy of a new [meta-tag:feature-request] meta question?

Comment: I see 0 posts tagged [status-by-design].

Comment: Oops, too many dashes! [meta-tag:status-bydesign] :)

Comment: @DavidG I agree this should be discussed further. Although this situation appears quite rarely, I think a significant proportion of users may miss the answer if it happens to them.