# How about a message to the question asker that a bounty was put on his question?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I just found out by coincidence that a bounty was put on my question, how about a message to the question asker that a bounty was placed onto his question?

In the comment section was a duplicate proposed. I see the connection between the question but is more thatn two years old, an nothing happened. I wanted to make a new question to dram attention to this topic.
Please don't close the question, it will improve the attention for this topic.

Comment: How does it affect the asker actually?

Comment: @user0042 The author of the question might've found the perfect solution but never posted it- a notification of a bounty on their question would enable them to post an answer detailing the solution and they might get the bounty.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299028/notify-authors-when-a-bounty-is-offered

Comment: Another two-and-a-half-year old feature request, and now that this question is closed, Stack Overflow management can breathe a sigh of relief and go back to monetizing the **** out of everything, confident in the knowledge that they've once again dodged a bullet. Can't have the core functionality of the site improved, after all!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A notification or two would certainly be in order. Actually I was surprised to hear this doesn't exist already!

- To know about a bounty posted on one of your questions might be encouragement for you to improve or clarify your question.
- They might have found an answer in the meantime, and be encouraged to provide it in detail in light of the bounty.
- Also, the question asker is uniquely equipped to spot abuse of the bounty system. They are in a great position to judge whether the winning answer actually provides value to the question.

Comment: Related: how about a message to the poster that an edit was made on its post? A poster is uniquely equipped to spot abuse of the edit system. They are in a great position to judge whether the edit actually provides value to the post.

Comment: @Cœur you do get a notification when a post of yours is edited, no?

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/not-notified-of-my-answer-getting-edited

Comment: @Cœur so you get a notification unless the system considers the edit minor. Whether that's right or not is certainly worth talking about, but it seems like a separate discussion...

Comment: Could you clarify point 3 please? How do you abuse the bounty system?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sock puppet accounts using them to transfer rep between each other. It's happened before.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299028/notify-authors-when-a-bounty-is-offered

Comment: @Pekka do you know if this was ever actioned? i.e. do askers get notified if a bounty is put on their question?